# Download PDF File Automatically without Redirecting to Viewer

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm trying to create a button on my webpage that automatically downloads a PDF file when clicked, without redirecting to the PDF viewer. Currently, when I click the button, it redirects to the PDF viewer instead of initiating the download.

Here's the HTML code for the button:

```
<a id="download-link" href="./Publications/SAMPLE.pdf" class="download-btn" onclick="download()">Download PDF</a>
```

And here's the JavaScript function I'm using:

```
<script>
    function download() {
      var link = document.getElementById('download-link');
      var fileName = link.getAttribute('href').split('/').pop();
      link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    }
</script>
```

I want the file to download automatically without leaving the webpage or redirecting to the PDF viewer. How can I modify my code to achieve this behavior?